# Node Js - get updated value from parent in child class

Tags: node.js, inheritance

I am trying to update  value in parent class and wants to access this in child class. But it is not giving me updated value.

```
class First {
    constructor() {
        this.value = 2;
    }
    updateValue() {
        this.value = 4;
        return this.value
    }
}

class Second extends First {
    constructor() {
        super()
    }

    getUpdatedValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
let first = new First();
console.log(first.updateValue()); // it is giving 4 i.e. updated
let second = new Second();
console.log(second.getUpdatedValue()); // but it still gives me 2
```

Comment: Look at `Second`. You're calling `getUpdatedValue` which has nothing to do with `updateValue`. There's no possible code path where `getUpdatedValue` would change `this.value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decide where the data is going to be. Should it be tied to an *instance*? Then call `updateValue` and `getUpdatedValue` from the same instance.

```js
class First {
    constructor() {
        this.value = 2;
    }
    updateValue() {
        this.value = 4;
        return this.value
    }
}

class Second extends First {
    getUpdatedValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
const instance = new Second();
console.log(instance.updateValue());
console.log(instance.getUpdatedValue());
```

Or should the data be persistent for all instances? Then it should be a static value on the superclass.

```js
class First {
    static value = 2;
    updateValue() {
        First.value = 4;
        return First.value
    }
}

class Second extends First {
    constructor() {
        super()
    }

    getUpdatedValue() {
        return First.value;
    }
}
let first = new First();
console.log(first.updateValue());
let second = new Second();
console.log(second.getUpdatedValue());
```

Comment: Thanks!! It was simple thing. I used second class instance to achieve my result.